# How do I combine a scrolling image with editable text in a SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I used a scrolling image code in the content editor web part and pasted my within the HTML source code editor.  I only modified the location for my image files.

How do I do combine functionality of image and updateable text where my scrolling image has text underneath without having to embed the text in the picture?

Ideally I would like this linked to a custom list that a content editor with limited programming knowledge can upload content and images that would refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Angela,

It is possible using JQuery/Javascript to call SPServices and get Custom List data in your script, and generate dynamic HTML

OR

Create Visual Web Part for this!

Don't know any Out of the box feature for this :)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using CQWP for this solution, i guess you can achieve this by using CQWP -

http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/07/sharepoint-scrolling-announcement-news.html

Comment: Can you provide some context for your link? Link only answers are generally frowned upon: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer